# Using beer as hair care product

Tags: health

Can I use any brand of beer on my hair? 
what are the things I need to consider before applying beer on to my hair?

Answer (score 5):

Before application, consider the steps you have taken to have gotten to that point, then do whatever you can to ensure you never repeat those steps again.

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember much of the advantages of using beer in your hair, but it was [popular in the 70s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNSCPod_Khk).  Variations across beer styles are much greater than variations across brands within a style, so if you know what style of beer you want to use, it should not matter much which brand you pick.  My recommendation is to go with the cheapest brand you can find within the style you want to use.